# Compositing did not apply to my Animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, animation-nodes, compositing-nodes

I'm new to blender and I was trying to animate a satisfying pendulum animation by CG Geek. I did all the steps, the problem I have is in the result of the animation. I did all the compositions like the denoise and the blue background he suggested but when I rendered my animation the compositing I did was not applied to the video.

I use blender 2.93. I really need help thank uu

Below is the compositing section of the blender.
[image]

The result of my animation when I rendered it is below.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. From your image, looks like you are not applying anything to your final render because the only thing connected to the composite node is the original image and not the other nodes. You are only connecting the nodes to a Viewer Node and you also need to do that to the Composite node

Answer (score 2):

(same as the comment but with an image) Hello and welcome. From your image, looks like you are not applying anything to your final render because the only thing connected to the composite node is the original image and not the other nodes. You are only connecting the nodes to a Viewer Node and you also need to do that to the Composite node.

[image]

Comment: that fixed my issue thanks @emir